# PrestaShop: How to load custom class (models) of my module

Tags: php, model-view-controller, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Hello i am working on prestrashop its new for and i am trying to develop a module in admin panel i create a model calss sizeguide but when i click on add its showing the error ,

> Fatal error: Class 'sizeguide' not found in classes\controller\AdminController.php on line 1614

i did try to fix it but i am not able to fix it even class is showing in class_index.php like this .

```
'Sizeguide' => array (
'path' => '',
'type' => 'class',
'override' => false,
),

 'SizeguideCore' => array (
'path' => 'classes/Sizeguide.php',
'type' => 'class',
'override' => false,
),
```

please help me to fix this issue thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, you may write to the PrestaShop version and the declaration of the class?

Comment: sizeguide != Sizeguide

Answer (score 0):

A `moduleadmincontroller` it's a little bit different of a `modulefrontcontroller`.

I'll write some guidelines.

*Naming*
The class name should be like this `AdminCONTROLLERNAMEController`.
For example:
    `class AdminGalleryController`

The complete declaration should be:

```
class AdminGalleryController extends ModuleAdminController
{
   // some stuff
}
```

*Add 'controller' in DB*
The new admin controller must be added in database, otherwise the dispatcher didn't find it.
This snippet add the new admin controller in the database:

```
$tab = new Tab();
foreach (Language::getLanguages() as $language) {
    $tab->name[$language['id_lang']] = $tabName;
}
$tab->class_name = 'AdminGallery';
$tab->module = /*yourmodulename*/;
$tab->id_parent = 0; 
/* 
* If you want to add as a child of some admin controller 
* that is in the backoffice menu you have to use this code: 
* (int)Tab::getIdFromClassName('AdminCatalog');
* With that code you add your controller as a child of 'AdminCatalog' controller
*/
$tab->save()
```

Usually this snippet should be added in `install` method of your module.

After that **to answer to your question**, your class should not be in `class_index.php`, your model should be placed in your module and be loaded by him.

For example in your module constructor you can add this snippet:

```
public function __construct()
{
   /* ... */
    require_once( _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->name . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'models' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Sizeguide.php' );
   /* ... */
}
```